# Socket does not sending anything unless run on debug mode

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, wifi

I am trying to communicate to an embedded device to get some readings to my android phone.

```
 public void ClickedLearn(View v){
    create_connection();
    request_packet();
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recieve_packet();
            if(isLearned){
                Savebtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            try {
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    },5000);
}
private void recieve_packet() {
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InputStream instream;
                instream = client.getInputStream();
                int a = instream.available();
                if (a > 0) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    final String Recievedstring = reader.readLine();
                    if (Recievedstring != null) {
                        Recieved_packet = Recievedstring;
                        isLearned=true;

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    while(t.isAlive());

}
private void request_packet() {
    OutputStream outstream;

    try {
        outstream = client.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);
        String outputPacket="T";
        textflag1=true;
        out.print(outputPacket);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void create_connection() {
    final String text = "192.168.43.161:80";
    final int port;
    final String ipaddress;
    if (text != null) {
        String[] splitted = text.split(":");
        ipaddress = splitted[0];
        port = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    client = new Socket(ipaddress, port);
                    isConnected = true;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        while (t.isAlive()) ;
    }
}
```

If I place a break point somewhere inside the request_packet everything works fine in the debugging mode. But it wont work in normal mode because the String on the outputstream is not sending. But the code is not throwing any exceptions. I don't understand what is going on 
please help me...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution. I was calling the send_packet function too early. I changed the ClickedLearn method a little and it worked for me.

```
 public void ClickedLearn(View v){
    create_connection();
    Handler communication=new Handler();
    communication.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            request_packet();
            Handler handler=new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recieve_packet();
                    if(isLearned){
                        Savebtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    try {
                        client.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },500);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: I don't see the `send_packet` in the code fragment from the question, is it in the server side?

Comment: The solution is to block in the read until data arrives, not to try to fiddle around with the timing. You don't know how long the data will take to arrive.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are misusing `InputStream.available()`. Entering debug mode changes the timing. Just remove the test.

And get rid of the `while (t.isAlive());` loop. If you want synchronous execution, why use a thread?

Comment: It didn't worked for me. I think I am calling the send_packet too early before establishing the connection. But what is wrong with InputStream.available()? I have used it several times before.

Comment: What is wrong with it is that it is pointless. You want the input: why not wait for it? Otherwise if `available()` returns zero you don't call `read()`, so you never receive the packet. Just block in `read()` until the data arrives. If you were calling it before establishing the connection you would get an exception, but if you called it before the data arrived you would get nothing, as you did. Which is why calling `available()` is pointless, and why removing it will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the `instream.available()` is non blocking and if the response from `192.168.43.161:80` did not yet arrived you'll get a `0` as result. Therefore the branch corresponding to `if (a > 0) {` will not get executed.  Now, when you enter the debug mode you just give the needed x milliseconds to the packets to arrive.

In order to synchronize with the server you could (as user EJB suggested) block and wait until data is available, thus get rid of `int a = instream.available()` and `if (a > 0) {`, jut use `reader.readLine()` it will block until data is available from server:

```
InputStream instream;
instream = client.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
final String Recievedstring = reader.readLine();
if (Recievedstring != null) {
  Recieved_packet = Recievedstring;
  isLearned=true;
}
```

As an extra feature you could set [socket timeout option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) which will affect  `readLine()` blocking time.

Comment: You are right. But i am giving plenty of time in the handler to arrive the bytes. The problem solved on giving a little time between the create_connection() and request_packet(). don't know the exact reason..

Comment: `InputStreams` are blocking. Get zero as an result of what?

Comment: @EJP, my mistake, I meant `inputstream.available()` instead of `client.getInputStream()` and I've updated my response; now, `available()` is non blocking and it could return `0` if no more data is available for reading